# Low-dimensional Irreducible Representations of $S_n$

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups

For $n\geq 7$, I would like to show that $S_n$ has no irredicuble representations of dimension $m$ for $2\leq m\leq n-2$.

The catch is that I am not allowed to use any "machinery" (evidently, this problem should be solvable having knowledge only of chapter 1 of Fulton and Harris).

At the moment, I don't really have any idea of how to approach this, especially without the use of character theory.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is not true. The tensor product of the sign representation and the standard has dimension $n-1$, and is not isomorphic to the standard.

Comment: Thanks David.  I'll edit the post to take this into account.

Comment: The case $n=7$ seems easy. Look at a 7-cycle. If it has a primitive seventh root as an eigenvalue, then it must have all six of them as eigenvalues, because it is conjugate to its non-trivial powers. That alone forces the dimension to be at least 6. OTOH if 1 is the sole eigenvalue, then all the 7-cycles would act trivially. Hence so would the subgroup that they generate, which is $A_7$... Alas, I cannot generalize this argument to higher $n$.

Comment: What about proving by induction that the only small irreducible reps of $S_n$ are the listed ones: two 1-dimensional, and two $(n-1)$-dimensional ones. So if $n\ge8$ is the smallest value with a counterexample, then the rep must remain irreducible when restricted to any of the $n$ conjugate 'point stabilizer' subgroups isomorphic to $S_{n-1}$. The restriction cannot be a sum of 1-dimensional reps, because then the copies of $A_{n-1}$ (and hence $A_n$) would act trivially. The remaining problem would be to show that neither of the $n-2$ reps of $S_{n-1}$ can be a restriction of a rep of $S_n$.

Comment: The result is true as stated for complex representations, but it is not true in general in other characteristics. For example, $S_n$ has a faithful irreducible representation of degree at most $n-2$ in characteristic $p$ whenever $p$ is a prime divisor of $n$ and $n >4.$ Take the obvious permutation module. Then $n$-long column vectors with zero sum form a submodule, but this submodule contains the span of the all-1 vector, which is invariant. I realise that characteristic 0 was the intent of the question, but it illustrates that the question is subtle.

Answer (score 5):

Following Jyricki's excellent suggestion, I will show that, for $n \neq 4$, the $n-2$ dimensional representations of $S_{n-1}$ do not extend to representations of $S_n$. Let $V$ be the vector space of $(n-1)$-tuples of real numbers adding up to $0$, with $S_{n-1}$ acting by permutation. I will show that this does not extend to an action of $S_n$.

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that there is an action of $S_n$ on $V$ extending the action of $S_{n-1}$. Since this is an action of a finite group in characteristic zero, it preserves a symmetric bilinear form. There is only one (up to scaling) $S_{n-1}$-invariant symmetric bilinear form on $V$ -- namely, the one induced from the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. So $S_n$ must preserve this inner product.

For $1 \leq i, j < n$, the transposition $(i j)$ acts on $V$ by orthogonal reflection in the vector $e_i - e_j$. Since $(i n)$ and $(i j)$ are conjugate in $S_n$, we know that $(i n)$ acts by orthogonal reflection in some vector; call it $v_i$.

For $1 \leq j,k < n$, with $i \neq j$, $k$, the reflections $(i n)$ and $(j k)$ commute. This means that $e_j -e_k$ and $v_i$ must be orthogonal. So $v_i$ must be of the form
$$v_i = a \cdot \left( \sum_{j \neq i} e_j - (n-2) e_i \right)$$
for some scalar $a$.

Now recall that ${\Large (} (ij) (in) {\Large )}^3 = \mathrm{Id}$. So the angle between $v_i$ and $e_i - e_j$ must be $\pi/3$ or $2 \pi /3$. We compute
$$|e_i - e_j| = \sqrt{2}$$ 
$$|v_i| = a \sqrt{(n-2)+(n-2)^2 } = a \sqrt{(n-1)(n-2)}$$
$$\langle e_i - e_j, v_i \rangle = a \left( -(n-2) - 1 \right) = - a (n-1).$$
So the angle between $v_i$ and $e_i -e _j$ is
$$\cos^{-1} \left( \frac{-(n-1)}{\sqrt{2(n-1)(n-2)}} \right).$$

When $n=4$, this is $\cos^{-1} (-\sqrt{3}/2) = 2 \pi /3$. And, indeed, when $n=4$, the action does extend! But for $n>4$, $\frac{(n-1)}{\sqrt{2(n-1)(n-2)}} \neq \pm \sqrt{3}/2$, so the action does not extend.

---

Now, a quick sketch of how to finish the problem from here. We prove by induction the statement

> For $n \geq 5$, the only representations of $S_n$ of dimension $<n$ are direct sums of (a) the trivial rep (b) the sign rep (c) the $n-1$ dimensional rep on $n$-tuples of numbers summing to $0$ and (d) the tensor product of (b) and (c).

The base case is left to you; starting by considering the eigenvalues of the $5$-cycle is a good idea.

Let $W$ be a rep of $S_n$ of dimension $<n$. Consider the restriction of $W$ to $S_{n-1}$. If $\dim W < n-2$, then induction shows that it is a direct sum of (a)'s and (b)'s, and I leave it as an exercise to show that $W$ is the same direct sum as a representation of $S_n$.

If $\dim W = n-2$ and $W$ is not made up of (a)'s and (b)'s, then $W$ is either type (c) or type (d). The above result gives a contradiction in the first case, and tensoring with the sign rep and then applying the above result gives a contradiction in the second case.

Finally, we must deal with the possibilities when $\dim V = n-1$. Details are left to you, but I think modifying the above argument will do this case as well.

Answer (score 2):

> **Theorem.** For $n \geq 7$, the only representations of $S_n$ of dimension $\leq n-1$ are direct sums of (a) the trivial rep (b) the sign rep (c) the $n-1$ dimensional rep on $n$-tuples of numbers summing to $0$ and (d) the tensor product of (b) and (c).

I'll use the induction hypothesis that the statement is true for $S_{n-1}$ and $S_{n-2},$ using $S_7$ and $S_8$ as base cases. **I haven't proved the base cases** but reliable references say they are true.
A similar induction was used in "Braid group representations of low degree‎" by Formanek to prove a result for the braid group.

It suffices to consider only unitary representations $\rho:S_n\to U_m,$ by the unitary trick as in [the other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/124729/467147). And we can assume $\rho$ is irreducible and faithful - otherwise it factors through $\det:S_n\to S_n/A_n.$

**Case 1.** The multiplicity of $-1$ in $\rho((n-1,n))$ is $1$ or $m-1.$

If the rank is $m-1,$ tensor with $\det$ to reduce to the case where the rank is $1.$ This case is then a representation as a reflection group: each $\rho((i,j))$ is reflection in the hyperplane perpendicular to a unit vector $v_{ij}$ which is determined up to phase.

For any subset $X\subset\{1,\dots,n\}$ with $|X|=n-1,$ the restriction to $S_X$ defines a representation $S_{n-1}\simeq S_X\to U_m.$ This representation is faithful and generated by $n-2$ reflections, so it's rep "(c)" of $S_{n-1}$ if $m=n-2,$ or the direct sum of that rep with a $1$-dim trivial rep if $m=n-1.$ This fixes the inner products between each pair of vectors $v_{ij},$ and hence determines $\rho$ up to isometry as being rep "(c)" of $S_n$ (and forces $m=n-1.$)

**Case 2.** The multiplicity of $-1$ in $\rho((n-1,n))$ is in $2,\dots,m-2.$

Let $V=V_{-1}\oplus V_1$ be the eigenspace decomposition with respect to $\rho((n-1,n)).$
The restriction of $\rho$ to $S_{n-2}$ (the symmetries of $\{1,\dots,n-2\}$) splits as $V_{-1}\oplus V_1,$ and each of these spaces has dimension at most $m-2\leq n-3.$ But this restriction must still be faithful. By the $S_{n-2}$ part of the induction hypothesis, this must be the (c) rep for $S_{n-2}.$
This forces $\dim V_{-1}=2.$
The $(-1)$-eigenspaces of any two disjoint transpositions in $S_{n-2}$ is a one-dimensional subspace of $V_{-1},$ which is independent of the choice of transpositions. So actually the $(-1)$-eigenspaces of any two transpositions in $S_{n-2}$ intersect in a fixed one-dimensional subspace, which is therefore a reducing subspace.

Comment: Thanks! The trick of going back to both $n-1$ and $n-2$ is simple but very slick.