# There is no $2$ dimensional, irreducible representation of $S_n.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

I am studying linear representation theory for finite groups and came across the claim in title. When $n\geq 5$, $S_n$ does not have an irreducible, $2$- dimensional representation.But I am not sure where to begin with.

Although it seems that this result will follow from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69384/low-dimensional-irreducible-representations-of-s-n) as a special case, I am interested in a solution that is specific to this problem.

The condition $n\geq 5$ seems to suggest that we need to use the fact that $A_n$ is simple for $n\geq 5$.

I would appreciate any hint.

Comment: Real or complex representation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a hint for one fairly elementary proof.

Suppose $\rho:S_n\to\textrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ is a representation, where $n\geq5$.

Consider the eigenvalues of $\rho(\sigma)$ for $5$-cycles $\sigma$.

Comment: I think I have shown that $\rho(\sigma)$ is the identity matrix.  If this is correct, what would be the next direction to go?

Comment: @dezdichado: consider the normal subgroup generated by the $5$-cycles.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks! 
I can see it now.

Comment: @dezdichado   I am still lost. Could you write down the detailed proof?

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to prove the following, using elementary methods of the above [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69384/low-dimensional-irreducible-representations-of-s-n):

> For $n \geq 5$, the only representations of $S_n$ of dimension $<n$ are direct sums of 
>   (a) the trivial representation 
>   (b) the sign representation 
>   (c) the $n-1$ dimensional representation on $n$-tuples of numbers summing to $0$ 
>   (d) the tensor product of (b) and (c).

We see that every $2$-dimensional representation then is reducible.
The argument with the eigenvalues for $5$-cycles is already given in the comments by Jyrki Lahtonen at the linked question, and by David Speyer in his answer.